# IPS for web application in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, ips, compliance

We have an application hosted in Azure under Kubernetes. In a security compliance document shared with us, there are multiple points mentioning about implementation of an IPS (Intrusion Prevention System). I understand the features and security offered by IPS.
I was wondering if this is really applicable in our case. Basically, I have 2 questions.

1. Is IPS necessary for web applications? Isn't it something implemented over an organization as such?
2. If IPS is good for medium sized web applications, can it be implemented for applications hosted in Kubernetes? What could be the challenges?

Answer (score 1):

My opinion - you should implement IDS/IPS if you can afford this. Nowadays security is one of the most important topics and sometimes it simply not enough regular firewall. For some organizations  even vital to have a good container security.

Yes, its possible use IPS with kubernetes.
There are few vendors. I will just leave you urls - you can check the opinions on them.

1) [Opinions on Intrusion Detection/Prevention Systems](https://www.reddit.com/r/kubernetes/comments/c3ei48/opinions_on_intrusion_detectionprevention_systems/)

2) [IDS/IPS for your EKS/Kubernetes Cluster](https://www.reddit.com/r/devops/comments/axmzp4/idsips_for_your_ekskubernetes_cluster/)

3) [Container security with Sysdig Falco](https://www.infracloud.io/container-security-sysdig-falco/)